# How to auto join my hidden SSID home network from my iPhone on iOS5

Tags: iphone, wifi, router

Ever since upgrading to iOS 5 my iPhone(s) have problems auto joining my home wifi network.

They seem to auto join it for a few days and then it just stops working.  The phone can still *see* the wifi networks if I go to settings->Wi-Fi, and once I do it will even auto-join it after a few seconds.  However; it only remains connected for a few minutes and then disconnects.

The only solution I've found so far is switching my Router's channel from *auto* to a specific number.  That works for a few days and then stops working again, if i bump the channel number in either direction it then works for a few more days.

This was a problem with my iPhone 4 after upgrading to iOS 5 and has been a problem with my iPhone 4s since purchase.

My (original) iPad has no issues and remains connected regardless of what I do to the router channel.

Comment: Have you tried telling your iPhone to forget the network and then re-joining it after it's forgotten?

Comment: Yup.  However; I should also note that I use a hidden SSID.

Comment: It may be an issue with your router. My iPhone works just fine with my hidden SSID (except if it sees a non-hidden one it knows about, it will tend to join it first).

Comment: It's not clear if this ever was resolved and it's also not clear if this question applies in general with changes to iOS, hardware. If anyone needs this open for an answer, please edit it and then flag for moderator review.

Answer (score 1):

Apple recommends not using hidden SSID's. There's no security in hiding them and as you have found out, it causes a problem with iOS devices discovering and joining the network after they come out of sleep mode.

Comment: That's not an answer.  I want a hidden SSID.

Comment: That *is* the answer. It keeps dropping the connection because you have a hidden SSID.

Comment: This is an an answer! By the way I think that hiding SSID's increase security...

Comment: @R.M. Not much, if any. Put a card in rfmon mode, and capture an association packet, and you have the SSID (even on a hidden SSID network). And you can often force reassociation.

Comment: since your question is 'why' this IS an answer. but maybe you could try [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Fix-an-iPhone-or-iPod-Touch-Losing-WiFi-Settings) ( adding the network manually )

Comment: Can you document Apple recommending non hidden SSID or provide a bug report that documents this being broken? I've not had such experience and would be interested to know if there is actually something technical to what you state.

Comment: It's possible to create a configuration profile (via **Configurator** from the Mac App Store or **iPhone Configuration Utility** for Mac and Windows) to program an hidden network, but I don't know if that will work around this issue.

Comment: Hiding your SSID is also a great way to not spam every else's WiFi settings with your private network, e.g., if you live in an apartment.

Comment: @bmike - howtogeek points out that hiding your ssid is, more-or-less, pointless: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28653/debunking-myths-is-hiding-your-wireless-ssid-really-more-secure

Comment: A hidden SSID does not add security. If the goal is securing your network, use WPA or preferably WPA2. The SSID was never designed to be hidden, and therefore won't provide your network with any kind of protection if you try to hide it. It's a violation of the 802.11 specification to keep your SSID hidden and a computer can refuse to communicate with an access point that doesn't broadcast its SSID. And, even if you think your SSID is hidden, it really isn't. For info here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/steriley/archive/2007/10/16/myth-vs-reality-wireless-ssids.aspx